# Transparent JList and Label on JPanel with image

Tags: java, swing

I am struggeling with a little exercise I teached myself: I have a JPanel with an image drawn by `g.paint()`. On this JPanel I have another `JPanel` (`componentsPanel`) that contains the actual content: a `JList` and a `JLabel` that I want to be transparent, so only the content is visible (no background of those elements)

Here are my classes:

The `JPanel` and its components

```
private void initializeNormalPanel() {
        normalPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                Image i, scaled = null;
                try {
                    i = ImageIO.read(new URL("image-from-url"));
                    scaled = i.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        CustomListModel listModel = new CustomListModel();

         //m1-m10 is the sample data
        listModel.addElement(m1);
        listModel.addElement(m2);
        listModel.addElement(m3);
        listModel.addElement(m4);
        listModel.addElement(m5);
        listModel.addElement(m6);
        listModel.addElement(m7);
        listModel.addElement(m8);
        listModel.addElement(m9);
        listModel.addElement(m10);

        JList list = new JList(listModel) {
            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        list.setCellRenderer(new CustomListCellRenderer());

        ComponentListener l = new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                list.setFixedCellHeight(10);
                list.setFixedCellHeight(-1);
            }
        };

        list.addComponentListener(l);
        normalPanel.setVisible(true);
        normalPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(normalPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JPanel componentsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel("Aktuelle Zeit", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        displayCurrentTime(timeLabel);
        list.setOpaque(false);
        componentsPanel.add(list, BorderLayout.WEST);
        componentsPanel.add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        list.setOpaque(false);
        timeLabel.setOpaque(false);
        timeLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));

        normalPanel.add(componentsPanel);
    }
```

I also have a custom `ListCellRenderer`:

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list, final Object value, final int index, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus) {
    final Meeting text = (Meeting) value;
    lt.setText(pre + value.toString());
    setOpaque(false);
    return p;
}
```

I cannot manage to achieve my goal, I always see the background of the List and Label. I tried every combination of `setOpaque` true and false, can someone help me to get my components transparent?

Comment: Post a proper [mre] when you ask a question. To test transparency all you need is a frame, your custom panel with an image, and a JLabel added to the custom panel. Get that working first. Then worry about the rest of the logic in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()` not paint.
2. Don't do I/O in a painting method. You don't want to keep reading the image every time the component needs to be repainted.
3. A JLabel is transparent by default (other Swing components are not).

> I always see the background of the List and Label.

```
normalPanel.add(componentsPanel);
```

I don't see where you make the componentsPanel transparent. So the background of the components panel will paint over top of the normalPanel.

Do you even need the componentsPanel? Why can't you just add the JLabel and JList directly to your normalPanel after setting the layout manager.

So first make sure it works with the JLabel since it is transparent by default. Once this works you know you have the proper layout. Then if the JList doesn't work you know you have a renderer issue.

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint with paintComponent! I did not see that I catched paint when using Strg+space ... :/